# Windows11で、使用されているTCPの輻輳制御アルゴリズムを知りたいです。

Tags: windows, tcp

Windows11で、使用されているTCPの輻輳制御アルゴリズムを知りたいです。
どのように確認すればよいでしょうか？

Ubuntuだと以下のコマンドで確認できます。これに相当することをWindowsで知りたいです。

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic
```

## Windowsの環境

```
エディション  Windows 11 Pro
バージョン   21H2
```

Comment: こんな資料があるようで、何かの参考になるかもしれません。[Low priority TCP Congestion Control in Windows - IETF ...](https://datatracker.ietf.org/meeting/112/materials/slides-112-iccrg-an-update-on-rledbat-and-bbrv2-00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C> netsh int tcp show supplemental

The TCP global default template is internet

TCP Supplemental Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Minimum RTO (msec)                  : 300
Initial Congestion Window (MSS)     : 10
Congestion Control Provider         : cubic
Enable Congestion Window Restart    : disabled
Delayed ACK timeout (msec)          : 40
Delayed ACK frequency               : 2
Enable RACK                         : enabled
Enable Tail Loss Probe              : enabled
```

ということで cubic だそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`int`はinterfaceの省略系ですね。